# How to edit lambda using the vscode aws extension (go)

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, visual-studio-code, aws-lambda

I created a lambda using the web gui, using Go 1.x. Now I want to edit the code but I don't know how. I downloaded the vscode extension but it only displays the lambda, doesn't give me any options for editing.

What am I doing wrong? How can I edit the code, and ideally run it locally and debug it?

All the tutorials cover how to create a function locally and then deploy it, but for another use case, I need to do it the other way around - there's already a deployed lambda and I need to edit it and write tests for it.

I have aws-cli, sam and docker functional.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From [Working with AWS Lambda Functions - AWS Toolkit for VS Code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-vscode/latest/userguide/building-lambda.html):

> The AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio Code provides support for AWS Lambda functions. Using the Toolkit for VS Code, you can author code for Lambda functions that are part of [serverless applications](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/). In addition, you can invoke Lambda functions either locally or on AWS.

So, looks like you can only edit Lambda components that are part of a SAM app.

Comment: There is now also a `Download` action on AWS Lambda resources in the AWS Toolkit (the docs still call this `Import...`, they need to be updated) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-vscode/latest/userguide/remote-lambda.html#import-lambda You can `Download` a Lambda function, do some edits, then `Upload` it again, which can be faster than the full SAM workflow.